# jquery toggle/addClass

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to change the class in the same action as this toggle effect that works on his own very well. (I have many Blocks that have the same classes)

```
$(".w_content").hide();
$(".w_target").click(function()
{
$(this).parent().next('.w_content').toggle();
});
```

if i add this code:

```
$(".w_content").hide();
$(".w_target").click(function()
{
$(this).parent().next('.w_content').toggle();
 $(".toggle").toggleClass("oN oFF");
});
```

it works on the first element. on the next it adds again the class on the first, and so on.

How can i append this only to the current toogle function.

the html looks like this:

```
<div id="somewhereBar" class="toggle oFF">

<div class="sharepost">
<div class="w_target"><a class="abc"></a></div>
</div>
<div id="abec" class="w_content">
<p id="text-selected" class="">text that should shown/hide</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="somewhereBar" class="toggle oFF">

<div class="sharepost">
<div class="w_target"><a class="abc"></a></div>
</div>
<div id="abec" class="w_content">
<p id="text-selected" class="">text that should shown/hide</p>
</div>
</div>
```

the oN/oFF classes should only change the height of the current parrent div to make the last nested div's text, visible.

i see that i use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. an `id` can on be used once on the page so you can't use `#somewhereBar` more than once
2. your `id`s weren't being called right: `id=#somewhereBar` is incorrect, you need to add quotes and remove the `#` like so: `id="somewhereBar"`

Then you can use `.closest` to traverse back to the container and toggle the two classes:

**JS**

```
$(".w_content").hide();
$(".w_target").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().closest(".somewhereBar").toggleClass("oN oFF").end().next('.w_content').toggle();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cyutccn9/1/)

**UPDATE**

The issue with this is that you did not change your `id` to a `class`. As I stated you can't use an `id` more than once on a page. Here is your code working but again, you need to change to what I have above:

[**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cyutccn9/3/)

Comment: i have seen that i use the same id's, i know. anyway it c'ant work with my code. the ".parent().closest" make it. thanks a lot!

Comment: @stevethemechanic so did that answer your question?

Comment: i must remove the last toogle. if not the text block is hidden and it works also without the .end().next() thanks

Comment: @stevethemechanic yeah there are several ways to do it. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You're using two elements with the same id: (remove #)

```
<div id="somewhereBar" class="toggle oFF">
```

Answer (score 0):

I d'ont know if is correct this way, but it works.

i added this before my code

```
$(this).parent().closest
```

now it looks like this

```
$(".w_content").hide();
$(".w_target").click(function()
{
$(this).parent().next('.w_content').toggle();
$(this).parent().closest(".toggle").toggleClass("oN oFF");
});
```

I guy's helped me a lot. sorry for editing the code again. The toogle class-name is now a little bit confusing i think.

Comment: This shouldnt be an answer, you need to respond in the comments. I updated my post so check it out. And please delete this